# What is root cause of getting debug log related to WL_AFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper_PACKAGE

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server, worklight-security

We are getting below logs in analytics console (client logs). Does any one has idea root cause behind this debug log.

```
Date    Thursday, Mar 10, 2016, 12:35 AM
Application Name    XYZAPP
Application Version 1.9.1
Operating System    ios
Device ID   BD39F272-D57F-45AC-AACE-3C0277BA796B
Device Model    iPhone8,1
OS Version  9.2.1
Package WL_AFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper_PACKAGE
Level   Debug
Message Response Error : Request failed: forbidden (403)
```

Answer (score 1):

A 403 means that no user is allowed to access that resource strictly FORBIDDEN. Not to be confused with a 401 which is UNAUTHORIZED (you just do not have the right credentials).

Unfortunately that is all we can determine from the error.

WLResourceReqeust uses WL_AFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper_PACKAGE and all request made by the client is a ResourceRequest.

Putting a few things together my guess is that this comes from when a user is trying to authenticate with the server. Occasionally we (the mobilefirst server) returns a 403 which is will be logged in the analytics console if you are sending debug logs.

Comment: What resource we are talking here? We don't have any adapter call in the application? so when we can expect such error?